# Second column into rows

Tags: html, css, css-tables

My coding is all over the place so i don't have any example of what i have so far. Looking to start over. I only seem to find how to convert All columns into rows while i only want the second column to do so.

Example of what i want to end up with:

[image]

I'm thinking a div table with two columns with the right one divided into two rows

I'm unable to use javascript and such due to restriction on the site.

I've been trying to search for it but due to too long away from coding and moss in the brain i just can't get it to fit together.

Help! Please!

Comment: the question seems to be very confusing! how does the image you tagged relate to the rows? Is that a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [`display: table;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) on a container `<div>` and `display: table-cell;` on the children `<div>`s, if you want to avoid the use of the `<table>` element itself:

```css
body,
html {
  background: black;
}
.table {
  background: #97a98e;
  display: table;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
h1,
p {
  color: #2a6e40;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2a6e40;
}
img {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Andreas, that worked absolutely perfectly! I always spend at least an hour on a problem myself before asking for help, this is just fantastic!

Now if I'd like two of those beside each other on the same page, how would that look like?

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! I'm sure you can figure that out for yourself, it's not that hard!

Comment: Yeah, i did in two seconds xD. Thank you!

Comment: I'm new so didn't know where to do that. Fixed it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
  <body>
    <table width="400" bgcolor="#97A98E">
      <tr>
        <td height="100" width="100" rowspan="2" bgcolor="blue">image</td>
        <td>Silver Shadow</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pretty flower</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```